# Usercontrol animation in C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, animation

Correct. I need any stupid sample of WPF Usercontrol animation in C# under the Canvas.
I tried all combinations under story.Begin(??????);
But it gives an error always. Any clue guys?

```
Storyboard story = new Storyboard();

DoubleAnimation dbWidth = new DoubleAnimation();
dbWidth.From = 0;
dbWidth.To = 200;
dbWidth.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.25));

DoubleAnimation dbHeight = new DoubleAnimation();
dbHeight.From = 0;
dbHeight.To = 200;
dbHeight.Duration = dbWidth.Duration;

story.Children.Add(dbWidth);
Storyboard.SetTargetName(dbWidth, PluginUControl.Name);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(dbWidth, new PropertyPath(UserControl.WidthProperty));

story.Children.Add(dbHeight);
Storyboard.SetTargetName(dbHeight, PluginUControl.Name);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(dbHeight, new PropertyPath(UserControl.HeightProperty));

story.Begin(??????);
```

**UPDATES:**

Also I tried to do like this

```
 story.Begin((MainWindow)App.Current.Windows[0]);
```

I guessed that it is the same story.Begin(this);
but no success...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342829/wpf-animations-in-a-user-control-learning-trying-to-understand-but-feeling

Comment: Thanks! But I need it done 100% by code behind in C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Dmitry Boyko:**

I found the solution guys!

It needs to replace

```
Storyboard.SetTargetName(dbWidth, PluginUControl.Name);
```

with

```
Storyboard.SetTarget(dbWidth, PluginUControl);
```